# Suppose that for two $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$ we have $AB = A + B$. Prove that $\text{rank}(A^2) + \text{rank} (B^2) \leq 2 \text{rank} (AB).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

> Suppose that for two $n \times n$ matrices $A,B$ we have $AB = A + B$. Prove that
> $\text{rank}(A^2) + \text{rank} (B^2) \leq 2 \text{rank} (AB).$

This reminds me of Sylvester's Rank Inequality theorem, but I'm not sure if that's really helpful here. I haven't really made significant progress on this beyond writing out a few matrix multiplication. Would appreciate any help at all! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1**: $B-I$ is invertible

In fact,
$$
Bv = v \implies Av = ABv = Av + Bv = Av + v\implies v=0.
$$

**Step 2**: $AB=BA$

In fact, since $B-I$ is invertible, in particular $(B-I)^{-1}=P(B)$ where $P$ is a polynomial (obtained by Euclidean division between the characteristic polynomial and $x-1$). So
$$
AB = A+B \implies A(B-I) = B \implies A = BP(B) = P(B)B
$$
and $A$ is thus a polynomial in $B$. In particular $AB=BA$.

**Step 3**: Profit

Notice now that $A^2 = P(B)BA$, so $rk(A^2)\le rk(BA)$ and the problem is symmetric in $B,A$, so $rk(B^2)\le rk(AB)$, leading to
$$
rk(A^2) + rk(B^2)\le  rk(BA)+ rk(AB) = 2rk(AB)
$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I have one doubt, however, when you define the polynomial $P$, you say that it's obtained by Euclidean division between the characteristic polynomial of $B$ and $x-1$, but I'm not sure why this is true. I know that the polynomial of the inverse of a matrix is the reciprocal polynomial of the characteristic polynomial, but could you please explain why we perform Euclidean division with $x-1$? Thanks again!

Comment: One last thing, how do you go from $A^2 = P(B)BA$ implying $rk(A^2) \leq rk(BA)$?

Comment: @OmicronGamma in general, $rk(XY)\le rk(Y)$ for every couple of matrices, since the null space of $XY$ contains the one of $Y$. If $Q(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $B$, you have that $Q(B)=0$; moreover, $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$, so $Q(1)\ne 0$. As a consequence, by Euclidean division, $Q(x) = S(x)(x-1) + c$ for some nonzero constant $c$, so we divide by $-c$ and $-Q(x)/c  = P(x)(x-1) - 1\implies -Q(B)/c = 0 = P(B)(B-I) - I\implies P(B) =(B-I)^{-1}$

Comment: I love this answer. Just one more clarification in case the OP has never seen it before: the step 'If $Q(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $B$, you have that $Q(B) = 0$' in the above comment is called the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, which is quite magical, but very useful in situations like this. See e.g. Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: @Vincent You can love this answer, but it is incomplete, proving only an inequality when, in fact, equality holds and it is elementary to prove, that is, there is no need to use Hamilton-Cayley. Actually, the answerer missed that $P(B)$ is an invertible matrix, so from $A^2=P(B)BA$ we get $rk(A^2)=rk(BA)$. Last, but not least, why do we need that $(B-I)^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $B$?

Answer (score 7):

There's a generalisation of Sylvester's Rank Inequality Theorem attributed to Frobenius. It states for all matrices $X, Y, Z$ we have
$$
rk(XY) + rk(YZ) \le rk(Y) + rk(XYZ).
$$
Using $AB = A + B$ we get $(A-I)(B-I)=I$ hence $(A-I) = (B-I)^{-1}$ and so $(B-I)(A-I) = I$ which implies $BA = A + B = AB$. So the matrices commute. Then apply the above theorem with $Y = AB$, $X = A-I$ and $Z = B-I$ gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 2):

The condition $AB=A+B$ is equivalent to $XY=I$ where $X=A-I$ and $Y=B-I$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
&2\operatorname{rank}(AB)-\operatorname{rank}(A^2)-\operatorname{rank}(B^2)\\
&=2\operatorname{rank}(X+Y+2I)-\operatorname{rank}(X^2+2X+I)-\operatorname{rank}(Y^2+2Y+I)\\
&=2\operatorname{rank}\big(X(X+Y+2I)\big)-\operatorname{rank}(X^2+2X+I)-\operatorname{rank}\big(X^2(Y^2+2Y+I)\big)\\
&=2\operatorname{rank}(X^2+I+2X)-\operatorname{rank}(X^2+2X+I)-\operatorname{rank}(I+2X+X^2)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Hence the inequality in question holds and it is actually an equality.